# How to Get Data Location Info of a BigQuery Dataset in script

Tags: google-bigquery

We are aware that when using `bq mk` command to create a dataset in BigQuery, we can use flag `--data_location` to specify which region we want table data under this dataset to be located in.

We are now wanting to set up a monitor so that whenever someone creates a dataset outside of our designated location, we can trig an alert to the dataset owner. In order to do this, we'll need a script that can automatically scan through all the datasets and get the location information. we looked at both api calls and bq command line tool commands, there's no clue with regarding to showing/inquirying data location of a dataset. Wondering if there's a way to accomplish our goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get all your datasets in the current project:

```
bq ls -d --format=json
```

If you run

```
bq show --format=json <dataset_name>
```

you get back a JSON that contains the `location` key:

```
{  
   "kind":"bigquery#dataset",
   "datasetReference":{  
      "projectId":"<edited>",
      "datasetId":"wr_temp"
   },
   "creationTime":"1479393712602",
   "access":[  
      {  
         "specialGroup":"projectWriters",
         "role":"WRITER"
      },
      {  
         "specialGroup":"projectOwners",
         "role":"OWNER"
      },
      {  
         "role":"OWNER",
         "userByEmail":"<edited>"
      },
      {  
         "specialGroup":"projectReaders",
         "role":"READER"
      }
   ],
   "defaultTableExpirationMs":"604800000",
   "etag":"<edited>",
   "location":"US",
   "lastModifiedTime":"1479393712602",
   "id":"<edited>",
   "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<edited>"
}
```

Also regarding API, if you run the dataset's GET call you get back the same JSON. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/get#try-it

Answer (score 2):

Add [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to extract `location` from the output.

```bash
bq --format="json" --project_id=<project> show  <datasetname> | jq -r '.location'
```

returns just the location.

```
australia-southeast2
```

If you wanted the project that owns the dataset

```bash
project=$(bq --format="json" show  <datasetname> |  jq -r '.datasetReference.projectId')
```

Answer (score 1):

> we looked at both api calls and bq command line tool commands, there's no clue with regarding to showing/inquirying data location of a dataset. Wondering if there's a way to accomplish our goal?

You can use API to accomplish this:

With [`Datasets: list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/list) API you can lists all datasets in the specified project

And then, with [`Datasets: get`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/get) API you can returns the dataset specified by datasetID and check dataset's [`location`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets#location) property

Comment: Keep in mind, that the location property is optional. I have seen it to be `undefined` for newly created datasets.